# UIPicker View not populating

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I'm trying to have 3 picker views populate. For some reason, all of them are showing up blank. Any idea why?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var seconds: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var minutes: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var distance: UIPickerView!

    var meters = [200, 400, 600, 800, 1000, 1200]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
       return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        switch pickerView {
        case minutes:
            return 100
        case seconds:
            return 59
        case distance:
            return (meters.count - 1)
        default:
            return 10
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        switch pickerView {
        case minutes:
            return String(row)
        case seconds:
            return String(row)
        case distance:
            return String(meters[row])
        default:
            return "ERROR 404"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` set

```
self.seconds.delegate = self  
self.seconds.dataSource = self
```

and so on for every pickerView

Comment: When using storyboards and outlets, connect the delegates and data sources in the storyboard. No need to add code.